# Android - Running endless code in Foreground while using the app

Tags: c#, android

Im making an application that i want to have the ability to send report emails with a frequency. daily, weekly or monthly.

Now i want those emails to be sent only if the app is running and if the user is using it (in my app you use the mobile as a kiosk, you open the app and leave it running all the time, screen will not close)

I have write this code in the MainActivity where if someone has enabled the frequently email feature, the activity will try to send the email (**SendStatisticsToEmailBySchedule()** will run forever and will use **SendStatisticsToEmail()** from time to time to send an email):

```
public async void SendStatisticsToEmail(string subject, string address, int port, string from, string to, bool useSSL, bool saveDateSent = false, string username = "", string password = "", bool sendNowButtonUsed = false)
        {
            var fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(
                GetString(Resource.String.Statistics_ExportAllExportPrefix,
                firstResult.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy"),
                DateTime.Today.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")));

            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(from));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(to));
            message.Subject = subject + " " + fileName;

            var statistics = new Statistics();
            var reportsForXML = statistics.ConvertRecordsForExport(MyData);
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            var builder = new BodyBuilder();
            var image = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.get_started);
            byte[] imgbyte;
            using (var bitmap = image)
            {
                var streamByte = new MemoryStream();
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, streamByte);
                bitmap.Recycle();
                imgbyte = streamByte.ToArray();
            }
            var imageAttach = builder.LinkedResources.Add(@"get_started.png", imgbyte);
            imageAttach.ContentId = MimeUtils.GenerateMessageId();
            builder.HtmlBody = string.Format(@"<p align=""center""><center><img height=""150"" width=""328"" src=""cid:{0}""></center></p><p align=""center"">{1}</p><p align=""center"">{2}</p><p align=""center"">{3}</p>", new object[] { imageAttach.ContentId, GetString(Resource.String.EmailExportSettings_MessageBodyLine1), GetString(Resource.String.EmailExportSettings_MessageBodyLine2), GetString(Resource.String.EmailExportSettings_MessageBodyLine3) });

            using (System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(stream))
            {
                reportsForXML.WriteXml(writer, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema, false);
                stream.Position = 0;
                builder.Attachments.Add(fileName, stream);
            }
            message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();

            try
            {
                using (var client = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    // For demo-purposes, accept all SSL certificates (in case the server supports STARTTLS)
                    client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, c, h, e) => true;

                    if (useSSL)
                        await client.ConnectAsync(address, port, SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect);
                    else
                        await client.ConnectAsync(address, port, false);

                    // Note: only needed if the SMTP server requires authentication
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
                        client.Authenticate(username, password);

                    await client.SendAsync(message);
                    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
                    if (saveDateSent)
                    {
                        Preferences.Set(Settings.ExportToEmailLastEmailSentKey, DateTime.Now);
                        ScheduleNextEmailForSend(DateTime.Now,
                            Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailEmailFrequencyPositionKey, Settings.ExportToEmailEmailFrequencyPositionDefault)
                            );
                    }
                    if (sendNowButtonUsed)
                        Toast.MakeText(this, GetString(Resource.String.Statistics_EmailSendSuccess), ToastLength.Long).Show();
                }
            }
            catch //(Exception exception)
            {
                if (sendNowButtonUsed)
                    Toast.MakeText(this, GetString(Resource.String.Statistics_EmailSendFailure), ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }
private void ScheduleNextEmailForSend(DateTime nextScheduledEmailDate, int frequency)
    {
        nextScheduledEmailDate = DateTime.Now;
        frequency = Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailEmailFrequencyPositionKey, Settings.ExportToEmailEmailFrequencyPositionDefault);
        switch (frequency)
        {

            case 0:
                Preferences.Set(Settings.ExportToEmailNextEmailForKey, nextScheduledEmailDate.AddDays(1));
                break;
            case 1:
                Preferences.Set(Settings.ExportToEmailNextEmailForKey, nextScheduledEmailDate.AddDays(7));
                break;
            case 2:
                Preferences.Set(Settings.ExportToEmailNextEmailForKey, nextScheduledEmailDate.AddDays(30));
                break;
        }
    }
```

This the the code that will run forever

```
private async void SendStatisticsToEmailBySchedule()
        {
            do
            {
                if (MyData.Count != 0)
                {
                    var currentConnectivity = Connectivity.NetworkAccess;
                    NextScheduledDateForReport = Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailNextEmailForKey, CurrentDateSettings.ExportToEmailNextEmailForDefault);

                    if (DateTime.Now > NextScheduledDateForReport)
                    {
                        if (currentConnectivity == NetworkAccess.Internet)
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                SendStatisticsToEmail(Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailSubjectKey, Settings.ExportToEmailSubjectDefault),
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailServerAddressKey, Settings.ExportToEmailServerAddressDefault),
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailPortKey, Settings.ExportToEmailPortDefault),
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailFromKey, Settings.ExportToEmailFromDefault),
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailToKey, Settings.ExportToEmailToDefault),
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailUseSSLKey, Settings.ExportToEmailUseSSLDefault),
                                    true,
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailUsernameKey, Settings.ExportToEmailUsernameDefault),
                                    Preferences.Get(Settings.ExportToEmailPasswordKey, Settings.ExportToEmailPasswordDefault)
                                );
                            }
                            catch
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                await Task.Delay(21600);
            } while (true);
        }
```

From what i have read here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Choosing-service-thread if you want to run some code only while the user is using your app, you should not use a service.

Is my code on **SendStatisticsToEmailBySchedule()** efficient?

Is there any situation that will stop working or should i somehow check that it is still working?

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a **System.Timers.Timer** for this job and the best way is to create it on **OnCreate**, pause it on **OnPause** and resume it on **OnResume**

```
protected override void OnCreate()
{
if(Timer_Is_Needed)
   SendStatisticsToEmailBySchedule();
}

protected override void OnResume()
        {
            StartSendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer();
}

private void SendStatisticsToEmailBySchedule()
        {
            SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer = new System.Timers.Timer
            {
                Interval = 3600000,
                Enabled = true,
                AutoReset = true,
            };
            SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer.Elapsed +=
                new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(OnSendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimerEvent);
            SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer.Start();
        }

        private void StopSendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer()
        {
            if (SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer != null)
                if (SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer.Enabled == true)
                    SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer.Stop();
        }

        private void StartSendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer()
        {
            if (SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer != null)
                if (SendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer.Enabled == false)
                    SendStatisticsToEmailBySchedule();
        }
        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            StopSendStatisticsToEmailByScheduleTimer();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Some quick remarks:

- `SendStatisticsToEmail()` is a *75 line* method with almost *a dozen arguments* and it does waaay too much. Split this method up into smaller methods -- for instance: one that gets the fileName, one that composes the body, etc. -- that do one single thing, and instead of passing so many arguments, pass a single class that has all these arguments as properties.

  (See for instance https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/27798/123339 on the "ideal" method length. Sure, this is personal and debatable, but once you need to scroll to read through the contents of a method you're probably on the wrong path and you'll need to refactor things.)

  Case in point: your method contains ten lines that are dedicated to converting an image into bytes. This should clearly be a method of its own instead of being chucked in the middle of this overlong mess. Another example: on line 17 you say `var builder = new BodyBuilder();` and then you don't use `builder` until line 27. This indicates a severe lack of structure and program flow.

  Even better: consider converting `SendStatisticsToEmail()` into a class with one `public` method and several `private` ones, instead of it being one method among many. You might even consider converting some of those `private` methods into classes of their own.
- One of the lines in `SendStatisticsToEmail()` is 450 characters long. This is unreadable and impossible to maintain. Even if you were to introduce some line-breaks, it would still be far too hard to maintain. Also, your email's body should really contain better HTML than what you currently offer.

  Instead, consider moving your email template to an embedded HTML file, with its variables to be filled in replaced by placeholders like `_ContentId_`. You read the embedded file into a string, and then have a method that loops through a `Dictionary<string, string>` where the keys are those placeholders and the values are the actual values.
- Why is the `if (saveDateSent)` logic inside the `using (var client = new SmtpClient())` block? Ditto `if (sendNowButtonUsed)`. These do not belong there. The whole `using (var client = new SmtpClient())` should be a method or even a class of its own, and that should return a `bool` to indicate success or failure, and that `bool` should then be used to trigger the logic the `if (saveDateSent)` logic and the `if (sendNowButtonUsed)` logic (and the UI logic now residing in the `catch` block).
- Avoid mixing UI elements into methods that should stay free of them. Sure, you need to report back on the success of sending an email to the user, but not from *inside* a convoluted method. Things like sending emails, calling the API etc. should be part of a service layer.

Comment: thank you very much for your comment, i had recently participate in MVC programming in a company and all those suggestions you said was among the first things i notice, I have a question however, you said in the first paragraph, i should make a class and pass all those arguments in the class. Why is this approach better from passing arguments to the method? i guess because all the needed code will be in a new class.

Also i have too tried to split better the code but i was getting a lot of exceptions i think because of the Context the android need to pass. I might was doing something wrong

Comment: Because that way you're less likely to make mistakes, and it makes it easier to adapt the method. New argument? Simply add it to the class, no need to update all use of the method. You're also less likely to confuse the various arguments. See also: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/145066/123339